# How to save a variable after runtime in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

Alright, so I am having issues with getting input from the user that will be used in the program until it is ran again with certain options in the cmd.

So say a user runs the program from cmd with the argument GUI, this will open a Tk window that asks for a their email, the user presses submit, and the text from the entry box is saved to a variable, now it will be able to use it for that runtime, but at the next run, say with no parameters, it will not have anything assigned to that variable since it was cleared from the memory.

I would find it ideal if I could just have it save the variable somehow after the runtime, since the user will use the program like so until they got a new email, then they would just run it with the option GUI again to assign a new one. Right now I am using a .txt to do that, but I find that a bit unsecure even after encrypting the email/pass with base64 since it can easily be unencrypted. How would I do this in a more safe, and more portable way, since a user can easily forget not to delete the file, and to move the .txt file to the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, base64 is not "encryption". It's just an encoding format, and saving anything in base64 will not protect it from being read.

I think the best solution for your case is to use some kind of system-level "keychain". Otherwise, just ask the password to the user every time it is needed, but of course that may become annoying.

Comment: Well it is meant to be ran at startup, and discretely, so if it just pops up a cmd every startup, it will completely ruin the point. Will XOR be good for encryption?

Comment: No, XOR is not considered to be a reliable encryption method. In any case, you need something to XOR the password with and that you will need to ask for next time the user wants to use the password. That means... another password. So, as you can see, there is no magical way you can encrypt a string and then be the only one to retrieve the original string without any extra information.

Comment: Alright, besides that how am I able to store the password, encrypted or not, past runtime.

Comment: You said yourself you are using a txt file. Just save it in plaintext, it won't be any safer saving it in any other encoding if it's not encrypted. If this is an app for a *nix system maybe you can create a `.yourappname` file inside user's `$HOME`.